# Is property HasRows available for iDataReader?

Tags: sqldatareader, idatareader

I ask the above question because I am seeing something property HasRows in the QuickWatch window..

I am modifying someone else's code, and need to follow the patterns established. I have to query a SQL Server table to retrieve a row from a configuration table, and decided to first code it in a test console app. I also decided to use the SQLClient types, and made use of property HasRows:

```
....
using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    if (rdr.HasRows)
    {
      ....
```

When I went to move the code to the other project, I noticed that IDataReader was used, and Intellisense said that the HasRows property wasn't available, so I used a while loop, even though I only have one row returning:

```
....
using (IDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
   while (rdr.Read())
   {
      ....
```

However when I performed a quick watch on the IDataReader rdr, I saw the HasRows property!

[image]

So can I easily get to the HasRows property for the IDataReader? If it really exists?

Answer (score 0):

No you can't. **HasRows** is an abstract method of **DbDataReader** and **IDataReader** don't have it.
Even so **DbDataReader** implements **IDataReader** it is implemented inside **DbDataReader** and not in interface itself.

Use **DbDataReader** in your code instead of interface.